# Ecto Datetime Error during insert

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to put in a datetime as insert_all doesn't add created_dates automatically and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
currentTime = DateTime.utc_now

query = from rm in ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasters,
            join: srp in ChatApp.Servers.ServerTypeParameters,
            where: srp.parameter_role_capable_flag == "Y",
            select: %{role_master_id: rm.id, server_type_code: srp.server_type_code, parameter_namespace: srp.parameter_namespace, 
                      parameter: srp.parameter, parameter_value: srp.parameter_default_value, 
                      user_changeable_flag: "Y", description: srp.description, 
                      active_flag: "Y", created_date: ^currentTime}

roleMasterRows = ChatApp.Repo.all(query)


ChatApp.Repo.insert_all(ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasterParameters, roleMasterRows)
```

My error message looks like this:

> value `{{2017, 5, 10}, {20, 28, 42, 0}}` for
>   `ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasterParameters.created_date` in `insert_all` does
>   not match type :utc_datetime

In the ecto.schema it turns the datetime into Tuples, but I am lost as to why it doesn't like mine.

I am stuck I went through the Ecto.Schema code and it looks like it wants tuples, but I am obviously missing something, thanks!

Comment: the default timestamp() calls in the migration and schema files are not utc. Make sure that both are the same. `timestamps(type: :utc_datetime)` in the migration file and in the schema file.

Comment: I appreciate the comment but I already fixed that!  I am not using the Ecto.Schema class already I wrote a macro to change the timestamps_opts to change the type already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to leave this here in case anyone else is having this issue.

The issue stems from the fact that because the query is schema-less and casts the created_date to erlang time.  Using:

> ^currentTime

When I go to insert_all here:

> ChatApp.Repo.insert_all(ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasterParameters,
>   role_master_rows)

It then tries to cast the erlang time to elixir and fails on the insert.

This is what I used to fix it:

```
current_time = DateTime.utc_now

query = from rm in ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasters,
            join: srp in ChatApp.Servers.ServerTypeParameters,
            where: srp.parameter_role_capable_flag == "Y",
            select: %{role_master_id: rm.id, server_type_code: srp.server_type_code, parameter_namespace: srp.parameter_namespace, parameter: srp.parameter, parameter_value: srp.parameter_default_value, description: srp.description}

role_master_rows = query
  |> ChatApp.Repo.all
  |> Enum.map(&( Map.merge(&1, %{user_changeable_flag: "Y", active_flag: "Y", created_date: current_time})))


ChatApp.Repo.insert_all(ChatApp.Roles.RoleMasterParameters, role_master_rows)
```